# Has anyone got evolution running for an activesync account please?

Tags: evolution, ms-exchange

Has anyone got evolution running for an activesync account please?
EWS is installed.
Instructions "Evolution-EWS and OAuth2 for Microsoft 365" followed.
Error message is »OAuth2 secret not found«.